# Is there a way achieve something like this in golang?

Tags: go

Current code looks like this(simplified version).

```
const (
    loginURL        = "http://test.xxx.com"
    authURL         = "http://test.xxx.com"
    tokenURL        = "http://test.xxx.com"
)
err := login(loginURL)
err = auth(authURL)
err = token(tokenURL)
```

Now I want to change the URLs depending on different situations.

```
const test(
    loginURL        = "http://test.xxx.com"
    authURL         = "http://test.xxx.com"
    tokenURL        = "http://test.xxx.com"
) // test block


const dev(
    loginURL        = "http://dev.xxx.com"
    authURL         = "http://dev.xxx.com"
    tokenURL        = "http://dev.xxx.com"
) // dev block

// if test, use test URLs; if dev, use dev URLs.

err := login(loginURL)
err = auth(authURL)
err = token(tokenURL)
```

Is there a way to achieve something like above? Or a better way?

Comment: Use variables instead of constants, which you may change at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use environment variables for that

```
var (
    loginURL        = os.Getenv("LOGIN_URL")
    authURL         = os.Getenv("AUTH_URL")
    tokenURL        = os.Getenv("TOKEN_URL")
)
err := login(loginURL)
err = auth(authURL)
err = token(tokenURL)
```